# Input str replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, replace

I want to replace in input this `/` by this `m.`.

My input looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="address1" id="address1" value=""/>
```

In input I write something like street_name 5/47 but in datebase I want it like street_name 5 m. 47

I try already:

```
var replit = $('input[name=address1]').val().replace("/"," m. ");
$('input[name=address1]').val(replit);
```

And

```
$('input[name=address1]').val(function(index, value) {
     return value.replace('/', ' m. ');
});
```

But this is not work form me, I'm new in programming, please give me any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `input` event to track user change inside the input field, then every time the user change in field the event will replace the slash `/` like a charm by `m.`.

### Snippet

```js
$('body').on('input', 'input[name=address1]', function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace('/', ' m. '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text" name="address1" id="address1" value=""/>
```

Or if you don't want from the user to see the replacement you do, you could replace the slash just after the submit in `submit` event :

```
$('body').on('submit', 'your_form_selector', function() {
     $(this).val($(this).val.replace('/', ' m. '));
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

Comment: Sorry for offtopic but I cant find how to mark Solved, after searching in google I found this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('input[name=address1]').val($('#input-field-id').val().replace('/', ' m. '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#address1').on('change',function()
{  
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace("/"," m. "));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=preco]').blur(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(value.replace('/','m. '));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that show your solution working: https://jsfiddle.net/e7n38wjz/2/
Please let me know if it is what you want. Do you know what JQuery version you are using? This JSFiddle was set up to use the JQUERY 1.6.4.

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="street_name 5/47"/>
<br>
<input type="text" class="text" name="address2" id="address1" value=""/>

// JS
var replit =  $('input[name=address1]').val().replace("/"," m. ");
$('input[name=address2]').val(replit);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Both of your examples work.** See here: https://jsfiddle.net/zreeLzo4/ and here: https://jsfiddle.net/q6awd8ng/

**So you need to better describe what "not working" means to you.** What happens that you don't expect? What didn't happen that you did expect?

**One thing to note:** using `replace` on a string will only replace the first instance of the match if you provide a string as the matcher instead of a regex. Use a regex with a global flag to replace all instances:

```
var startString = 'street_name 5/47 something/else';
var endString = startString.replace(/\//g," m. ");
console.log(endString); // <- street_name 5 m. 47 something m. else
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that only the entry in database should use 'm' instead of '/', then you should consider changing the input value wherever you are writing this data to database. You should consider making use of the .submit() event in the following way :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#detailForm").on("submit", function(){
            var value = $('input[name=address1]').val();
            value = value.replace("/", " m. ");
            $('input[name=address1]').val(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```